# How to setup a access point on my raspberry pi zero w? (Re-Ask)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, localhost, raspbian

this is a duplicate of my first question. Since I found out more info about the topic, but not the answer yet, I will update the question. Here is the new info I found out:

- My TP-Link WN722N eu is version 4.0
- I bought it here (if it helps): [Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/TP-Link-TL-WN722N-High-Gain-Antenne-WLAN-Empfang-unterst%C3%BCtzt/dp/B002SZEOLG/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3M9RK0SDMQN8O&keywords=tp+link+wn722n&qid=1687279260&sprefix=tp+link+wn722n%2Caps%2C110&sr=8-2)

Here is the original question:
I have recently bought a Raspberry Pi zero w and installed Raspbian Lite (x32). I have read quite a few articles on the question I am about to ask, but didn't find the answer that works for me.

In a few weeks I will go on a trip where I want to take my Raspberry pi with me. On it I have coded a php webserver with mysql for files, etc. As I won't have any wifi/internet at the place I'm going to, I wanted to ask if the following things could be done and how:

- Hotspot like AP on the Pi using TP-Link WN722N
- Connecting to it from my laptop/phone
- Being able to access the localhost server on Pi from laptop/phone
- Host AP, Connect to it and access localhost without Wifi/Mobile Data

Comment: You might get more joy if you posted it on [Raspberry Pi site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)